# Path setup in Fish shell

Tags: laravel, composer-php, fish

Laravel requires to set path. It's done by

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

in bash but I need it be done in fish shell persistently.
I tried to set it by set -u  in ~/.config/fish/config.fish but doesn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In fish, $PATH, $MANPATH and $CDPATH are automatically converted to lists.

That means the fish-native equivalent of your command (which will actually work as it is in 2.6.0 because fish ships a `export` compatibility function) is

```
set -gx PATH $PATH $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Now, you do *not* want to set $PATH universally. You also pretty much can't, because it is inherited from the parent process in 99% of cases as a global variable, and global variables override universals (meaning the univeral variable is pointless).

However, fish has a `$fish_user_paths` universal variable that it will prepend to $PATH, so you can also use

```
set -U fish_user_paths $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

If you need to *append* instead, you'll need to add that $PATH snippet above to your config.fish.

Comment: for future growth, use `set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` to append instead of replace

Comment: Note: Do _not_ do that in config.fish - that will cause $fish_user_paths to grow without bounds.

Comment: With the commands above I got:
> set: Warning: universal scope selected, but a global variable 'fish_user_paths' exists.